# What is the point when the profinite topology of a group $G$ induces the full profinite topology on a subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, profinite-groups

I have a question. I don't know if is trivial or even it makes sense, but is something I could not understand. For example, consider the following exercise of Ribes-Zalesskii:

**Exercise 9.1.1** *Let $G = A \ast B$ be a free product of abstract groups. Prove that $G_{\widehat{C}} = A_{\widehat{C}} \bigsqcup B_{\widehat{C}}$.*

In this case, C can be considered as a variety of groups finite groups, $(\cdot)_{\widehat{C}}$ means the pro-C completion and $\bigsqcup$ means the free pro-C product.

He gives two hints. First, the obvious hint is to use the universal property. My question arises on the second hint: "use Corollary 3.1.6".

This corollary says that

> If $G = L \ast H$ then

> (a) The pro-C topology of $G$ induces on $H$ its full pro-C topology

> (b) If $G$ is residually C, then $H$ is closed in the pro-C topology of $G$.

There is a lot of other results like this: if $G$ has something hypothesis, then the pro-C topology induces the full pro-C topology on some subgroup.

*What is the relevance of this fact?* I mean, in the case of **Exercise 9.1.1** I think (correct me if I'm wrong) it ensures that the pro-C completion of $A$ and $B$ will be closed subgroups in the pro-C completion of $G$ and this is important to decomposition as free pro-C product.

But I cannot see how is it explicit used to solve this problem. It seems essentially a problem solved with universal property and I cannot see the point where this is relevant.

---

Trying to be more clear, I would like to know exactly where this corollary is fundamental to solve this exercise. I don't need necessarily a proof of the exercise, I want just want to see why the result is necessary. I think is just to ensure that the pro-C completions of $A$ em $B$ will be pro-C groups but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: I don't understand what is the statement to be proved. It looks like "Prove that [some expression/construction]".

Comment: I also don't know what this $C$ is. (It's probably a good idea to make the question self-contained, for the sake of readers without access to this book.)

Comment: @user43208 I have edit the question

Comment: I think you missed the point of the first comment. Exercise 9.1.1 looks like it has been mis-stated. *Prove that $A_{\widehat{C}} \bigsqcup B_{\widehat{C}}$* is not a complete sentence. Are you asked to prove that $A_{\widehat{C}} \bigsqcup B_{\widehat{C}}$ is pink? That it has feathers? That it is a compact metrizable $3$-manifold?

Comment: @LeeMosher Oh, I apologize. In my mind I had written correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the importance of the corollary in the context of Exercise 9.1.1 is that it ensures that the pro-C completions of $A$ and $B$ will be closed subgroups in the pro-C completion of $G$. This fact is crucial for the decomposition of $G_{\widehat{C}}$ as the free pro-C product of $A_{\widehat{C}}$ and $B_{\widehat{C}}$. Let me explain this more explicitly.

In order to show that $G_{\widehat{C}} = A_{\widehat{C}} \bigsqcup B_{\widehat{C}}$, we need to show that the pro-C completion of $G$ has the desired decomposition, which means that $A_{\widehat{C}}$ and $B_{\widehat{C}}$ should be closed subgroups of $G_{\widehat{C}}$. This is where Corollary 3.1.6 comes into play.

Part (a) of Corollary 3.1.6 says that the pro-C topology of $G$ induces on $H$ (in our case, $A$ and $B$) its full pro-C topology. This implies that the pro-C completion of $A$ and $B$ will be closed subgroups in the pro-C completion of $G$, as we wanted.

Part (b) of Corollary 3.1.6 further states that if $G$ is residually C, then $H$ (in our case, $A$ and $B$) is closed in the pro-C topology of $G$. This fact reinforces the importance of the pro-C completion of $A$ and $B$ being closed subgroups in the pro-C completion of $G$.

Now that we know that $A_{\widehat{C}}$ and $B_{\widehat{C}}$ are closed subgroups of $G_{\widehat{C}}$, we can proceed to show that $G_{\widehat{C}}$ is indeed the free pro-C product of $A_{\widehat{C}}$ and $B_{\widehat{C}}$ using the universal property.

To summarize, the relevance of Corollary 3.1.6 in Exercise 9.1.1 is to ensure that the pro-C completions of $A$ and $B$ will be closed subgroups in the pro-C completion of $G$. This fact is essential for establishing the decomposition of $G_{\widehat{C}}$ as the free pro-C product of $A_{\widehat{C}}$ and $B_{\widehat{C}}$.